# VNA measurement of a domestic 3 wire AC cable used as a parallel transmission line

Tags: filter, transmission-line, vna

I am currently working on power line communication techniques for low and medium bandwidth applications. I was curious to calculate Z0 on a 3 wire, 1.5mm2 power cable. The theoretical impedance of a parallel transmission line calculation works only for 2 wires, and since there is a protective earth conductor, I doubt it could be calculated easily.

So I'll need to measure it. (open circuit, then short circuit of phase/neutral)
After that I will perform real world measurements (S11/S21) on a live cable/outlet, and i will use a 275V AC 0.044uF filter capacitor and a pulse 1:1 transformer t3001nl for each port as a HPF and then work on from here. If the 50 Hz / 230V AC is sufficiently attenuated, I should not fry my VNA.

Then I will make more measurements on different outlets in the house.
Since it is an improvised transmission line with branchings at the power panel, I'll expect to have wildy variable measurements.
my frequencies of interest are in the 2 Mhz to 900 Mhz range. I don't want to pass too much low frequency in my filter to keep AC 50 hz levels low.
Any safety advice or other tips for that kind of measurements ?

Comment: This doesn't answer your question but my experience with power line comms both inside and outside the home has taught me that impedance varies widely depending on what devices are connected to the line, how its wired, what the junctions are like, etc, etc :)

Comment: yes, that is what I thought. maybe ten years from now we will have miniaturized automatic tuners for small power (15 dbM) at reasonable prices. In UHF bands and up they would not have a huge footprint... However, if the modulator / RF chip is set at a fraction of its max power level, the mismatch should not fry the chip I hope.

Comment: *This question is likely to be answered with opinions rather than facts and citations. It should be updated so it will lead to fact-based answers.* - why not ask a proper question?